# Rally App SDK 2.0: rallyaddnew errors when clicked and does not expand and show "Add with Details" button

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I have tried to implement a rallyaddnew button, and using the configuration provided in the example, I receive the following error when I click on the button (this is also the case in the "Live Preview":

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getContextPath' sdk.js:59857 
    a.define._onNewClicked sdk.js:59857 
    fire sdk.js:4371
    Ext.define.continueFireEvent sdk.js:13154 
    Ext.define.fireEvent sdk.js:13140 
    a.define._interceptBefore.c.(anonymous function) sdk.js:56055 
    Ext.define.fireHandler sdk.js:40307 
    Ext.define.onClick sdk.js:40303 
    (anonymous function) 
    Ext.apply.createListenerWrap.g sdk.js:4766
```

The component fails to expand to show a text field and the “Add with Details” button.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known defect in SDK preview 2.0p3 and will be addressed with the next version.

Your App will work properly inside of a custom App Panel in Rally though.

Comment: By a "custom App Panel," do you mean a "custom HTML app"?

Comment: Sorry about that you are dead on.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused as to what you meant by the app will work. The rallyaddnew does not function properly within my test app. Also, by "next version," did you mean an upcoming weekly release? Or 2.0p4?

Comment: 2.0p4 We do not patch existing versions of the SDK so 2.0p3 will always work the same and new features will always be released with an incremented version

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I will go ahead and leave this question open until it has been resolved with a new release.